# Laravel delete my file cache for admin user but not standard user

Tags: laravel

I store in the cache when a user logs in and keep it for 1 minute, when I log in/out with a user named 'user' it works, I can access the cache, but when I log in with a user named 'admin' I access his cache but when he logs out I get this error :

```
<warning>PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/sitename/storage/framework/cache/data/16/6a/166a6e572c2df9368c554ead296c3ea04636d1d6): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/sitename/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 70</warning>
```

Could it be because the user is called 'admin' and automatically thinks it's a "secret" file that can't be opened?

I recover the cache with tinker and a Cache::get()

```
Cache::get('user-is-online-52a1778c-c0d7-4de4-aa8b-a9a7931b5074')
```

Edit : The cache for the user is not deleted after logging out, while for the admin the cache file is deleted... I don't understand why

There is the code to store the cache :

```
if(Auth::check()) {
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of the key first to get rid of the :get error

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    if (Cache::has('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id)) {
       $my_cache= Cache::get('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

How are you deleting keys at logout? Does it come before or after the logout?

Comment: When I disconnect I don't delete anything (normally), everything is by default at this level. It disappears only when the user has an admin name, it is incomprehensible

Comment: A priori nothing to do with the admin name, there is a problem at the disconnection, I lose the cache. Where could it come from ? I do a flush and an Auth::logout() only

Comment: I'm not sure,  what auth package are you using?  Is it just expiring the cache value after 1 minute?   I may be confused on whats going on.  You are caching a user online key when a user logs in or each page load?    The problem is when you log out with a normal user it stays until expires but when you log out with an admin it removes itself immediately ?

Comment: No package, basic auth. It's very strange. When I log in with the user with the name "user" it keeps the cache for me. With the user "moderator" or "admin" it deletes the cache file. I just made a user "random_name" and it works like with user, it does not delete. It is to understand nothing. It is a middleware on each request.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for that, I had a trait that clear hides it when there is an interaction on a model...

```
trait CacheClear
{

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        /**
         * After model is created, or whatever action, clear cache.
         */
        static::updated(function () {
            Cache::flush();
        });

        static::saved(function () {
            Cache::flush();
        });

        static::deleted(function () {
            Cache::flush();
        });
    }

}
```